# graph api explorer doesn't return the same as the Get response from the visual

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I have a strange problem.

I have a string of ad groups ids.. it's splited by commas.

I used `graph api explorer` of facebook in order to get the total spent of all of these ads.

so I call something like:

```
act_ACOUNTID/adgroupstats?adgroup_ids=[AD_GROUP_IDS]&start_time=
2009-05-18T07:00:00&end_time=2014-05-19T07:00:00&limit=100&offset=100
```

In the result there are 42 rows (total rows is 142, but I used `offset` (get from the 100'th rows) and `limit`(show only 100`th rows) so there is no problem yet).

In my visual, I make the same call:

```
int ADS_LIMIT = 100;
int offset = 100;

IDictionary<string, object> result = facebookClient.Get("/act_" + accountId +
"/adgroupstats?adgroup_ids=[" + adGroupIds + "]&start_time=" + startTime + 
"&end_time=" + endTime + "&limit=" + ADS_LIMIT + "&offset=" + offset, parameters)
as IDictionary<string, object>;

var DataResult = result["data"] as List<object>;
```

but `DataResult.Count` contains 100 rows and not 42.

can someone guess why this problem happened? (p.s. I copy and paste the string in the code to the facebook graph api and set the access token so there is no problem with it)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

facebook answered me for this issue:

```
In this case this is not a bug and is in fact by design. Limit and Offset 
pagination is not supported across all endpoints and in the Ads API we recommend
that you instead use the "next" & "previous" paging links. This is highlighted
here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#paging
```

Comment: For future reference, this sort of thing should probably be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

(For future reference:) Just as you said, the first thing to do to tackle something like that, is to look at the resulting string.

In your case:

```
Console.WriteLine("Created String: " + 
    "/act_" + accountId +
    "/adgroupstats?adgroup_ids=[" + adGroupIds + "]" +
    "&start_time=" + startTime + 
    "&end_time=" + endTime + 
    "&limit=" + ADS_LIMIT + 
    "&offset=" + offset);
```

1. Just looking at the finished string (like you did) you might see something that's wrong
2. If not so, you check what result you get from calling it directly (like you did)
3. If the result there is fine as well, the problem must lie further within. For example you would probably look at what the `facebookClient.Get(..)` method does exactly ...

Which can be a really aggravating point to reach, since you don't always have the source to debug, or even worse when the requests from your SDK are handled in a different way, than the direct api calls and you pretty much can't do anything to fix it. (Other than reporting it or asking on SO ^^)